# How do I dynamically count all rows that have a null value across all tables and columns in a database schema

Tags: database, t-sql, count, null, isnull

I need to create an exception report that looks over all the tables in a specific schema, which then counts across columns and rows and lists how many entries per column there were that contained a NULL Value.

How is this done without the use of cursors?

*Example:*

> People_Table has 3 Columns (NAME, SURNAME, CONTACT_NO) 
>   Entity_Table has 5 Columns (ID, NAME, ADDRESS, TEL_NO, FAX_NO)

I need to produce an output that lists each table and column name along with how many records contained a NULL value within each of the Columns.

> People_Table : NAME (4), SURNAME (9), CONTACT_NO (120) 
>   Entity_Table : ID (0), NAME (4), ADDRESS (90), TEL_NO (120), FAX_NO
>   (100)

Please note that the output can be in a regular dataset format and doesn't need to look like a concatenation of entries! I only listed it in that manner to describe the data output.

This is for a dynamic database that changes over time as a column that at this stage that doesn't have any NULL entries may have a NULL entry in the future, so I need to track this. So far I've done other stuff towards this solution and this is the last of what I need now. Any advice??

Comment: What's wrong with using cursors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @dbname VARCHAR(100) = 'dbname'
DECLARE @schemaName VARCHAR(100) = 'schemaname'
DECLARE @result TABLE ([NullValues] int,col VARCHAR(4000))

SELECT  @dbname dbname
        ,t.name tbl
        ,c.name col
INTO    #Temp1
FROM    sys.columns c
JOIN    sys.tables t ON 
        t.object_id = c.object_id
JOIN    sys.schemas s ON 
        s.schema_id = t.schema_id
WHERE   c.is_nullable = 1
AND     s.name in (@schemaName)

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) =
STUFF(
(
    SELECT  'UNION ALL SELECT Count(*) as [NullValues],''' + @dbname + '.' + @schemaName + '.' + tbl + '.' + col + ''' FROM ' + @dbname + '.' + @schemaName + '.' + tbl + ' WHERE ' + col + ' IS NULL '
    FROM    #Temp1
    FOR     XML PATH('')
), 1, 10, '   ')

INSERT @result
EXEC(@sql)

SELECT  [NullValues], col
INTO #Nulls
FROM    @result
WHERE   col IS NOT NULL AND [NullValues] > 0

SELECT
       [TABLE_CATALOG] + '.' + [TABLE_SCHEMA] + '.' + [TABLE_NAME] + '.' + [COLUMN_NAME] as SchemaTableColumn
      ,[TABLE_CATALOG] as 'Database'
      ,[TABLE_SCHEMA] as 'Schema'
      ,[TABLE_NAME] as 'TableName'
      ,[COLUMN_NAME]
      ,[ORDINAL_POSITION]
      ,[DATA_TYPE]
INTO #Temp2
  FROM [DW_LandingCR].[INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[COLUMNS]
  WHERE
    [TABLE_SCHEMA] = @schemaName
  ORDER BY TABLE_SCHEMA,TABLE_NAME,ORDINAL_POSITION

SELECT sc.name as [Schema],ta.name as [TableName],SUM(pa.rows) RowCnt
INTO #Temp3
 FROM sys.tables ta
 INNER JOIN sys.partitions pa
 ON pa.OBJECT_ID = ta.OBJECT_ID
 INNER JOIN sys.schemas sc
 ON ta.schema_id = sc.schema_id
 WHERE ta.is_ms_shipped = 0 
 AND pa.index_id IN (1,0)
 AND sc.name = @schemaName
 GROUP BY sc.name,ta.name
 ORDER BY sc.name,ta.name

Select 
    tp2.*,tp3.RowCnt 
Into #Detail
From 
    #Temp2 tp2 
    inner join #Temp3 tp3 on tp2.[Schema]=tp3.[Schema] and tp2.[TableName]=tp3.[TableName]

Select
    det.*,
    n.[NullValues]
From
    #Nulls n
    Inner Join #Detail det on det.SchemaTableColumn=n.col
Order By
    det.[Database],
    det.[Schema],
    det.TableName,
    det.[ORDINAL_POSITION]


Drop Table #Nulls
Drop Table #Detail
Drop Table #Temp1
Drop Table #Temp2
Drop Table #Temp3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (uses cursors though):

```
DECLARE @tbl sysname
DECLARE @col sysname
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @cnt INT

CREATE TABLE #result
(
    tbl sysname,
    col sysname,
    nulls int
)

DECLARE crs CURSOR FOR 
select t.name, c.name
from sys.columns c
join sys.tables t on c.object_id = t.object_id

OPEN crs

FETCH NEXT FROM crs INTO @tbl, @col

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
BEGIN

    SET @sql = 'select @cntOUT=count(*)  from '+@tbl+' where '+@col+' is null'

    SET @cnt = 0
    exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@cntOUT INT OUTPUT', @cntOUT=@cnt OUTPUT

    INSERT INTO #result (tbl, col, nulls)
    VALUES (@tbl, @col, @cnt)


    FETCH NEXT FROM crs INTO @tbl, @col
END

CLOSE crs
DEALLOCATE crs

SELECT * FROM #result

DROP TABLE #result
```

Comment: thanks for the effort. I needed to prevent the use of cursors for performance reasons as this script will be plugged into any database with any formatting and it will return the related details. Very quick response from your end and that makes me more comfortable with this forum. I'm gonna post my answer now!

Comment: Oh gosh, now I've got to spend time on formatting the code to the forums requirements. When I have the time to do that then I will place my answer here. I could also post my entire Stored Proc but would need to copyright it because this is a simple way to check consistency across an entire Data Warehousing Database and would be beneficial for any developer. This Proc was for use in a Data Warehousing Environment

Comment: So you found a way to do this without cursors? Curious to see your solution.

Comment: Yes I managed to do it without cursors. I simply built a temp table and gathered all the info I needed from using the sys objects in SQL. I then added a script parameter that concatenated a large string which built up a UNION ALL Select Count(*) From @dbname.@SchemaName.@tablename@.@ColumnName Where @ColumnName is null. I then linked it to my existing list of columns in another temp table and 'woop,woop' it worked like a charm. This can be used against any database structure on any server.

Comment: I will post my entire script soon. Is there a way I can simply save the .sql script file without me having to now go in and format it according to this sites requirements? It's not that my layout is poor, it's just a lot of code and I'm not used to this coding engine...